# C++ compilation broken on OS X 10.9

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, osx-mavericks

I just upgraded my Mac to Mavericks, and find that none of my C++ code will compile anymore.  Everything fails with the following errors:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:147:22: error: missing binary operator before token "("
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:176:18: error: missing binary operator before token "("
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__config:184:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("

etc.

I have no idea what that file is, but it seems to get included from lots of standard headers, like cassert and string.  I looked it up, and here is line 147:

```
#  if __has_attribute(type_visibility)
```

Any idea what's going on?  All of this code worked perfectly before the upgrade.  I also made sure Xcode is fully up to date (5.0.1).

Comment: Did you update Xcode command line tools? `clang --version` should report: `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) , Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0, Thread model: posix`. Also, your project files will need to be updated if you're using Xcode, and will prompt you to do so (or at least should) upon first opening.

Comment: Yes, that's what I get.

Comment: I'd check your project file and make sure its referencing the right toolset, set it to the 10.9 SDK if needed. Tis an odd error to be sure.

Comment: I'm building from the command line, not through the Xcode app.  But yes, I specify "-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk".

Comment: What's the status on this? I would like to upgrade but am obviously now concerned.  Did you get it to work?  If so what steps were required?  Thanks!